# How to show tooltip on @ng-select/ng-select options

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am using @ng-select/ng-select@2.3.6 in my application and i have a very long text in array.

So, the complete text not visible in dropdown list so I want to show the title/ tooltip over the each and every options

I tried,

```
let listArray = [{name: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s'}];

<ng-select placeholder="Select" (change)="onChange($event)">
      <ng-option *ngFor="let list of listArray" 
       title="{{list.name}}"> {{list.name}} </ng-option>
 </ng-select>
```

But no luck

Comment: Well, it's probable that there is a max-length. Shorten your text for testing purposes to 1 word and have a look whether this works at least.

Comment: I have shorten text as well but issue still exist.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

you can achieve tooltip solution using below code

```
<ng-select [items]="listArray" bindLabel="name" bindValue="name">
    <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item">
    <div title="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</div>
    </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the answer. What if we need to show the title for a selected item?

Comment: @atitpatel can you please add example or code about what you exactly need?

Comment: In this example... stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wziwui?file=src/app/… I select first option.. "Loreum....." after selection ... We can see selected item...When I hover on the selected value... I would like to see the title( as the name is too big and user cant see full value)same as when I open dropdown options and hover over... I am able to see title.

Comment: @atitpatel
Add "[title]="Selected" to ng-select and it will display selected value on hover.

<ng-select [items]="listArrayManyElements" placeholder="Select" [(ngModel)]="Selected" bindLabel="name" bindValue="name"
 [title]="Selected">
 <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item">
  <div [title]="item.name">{{item.name}}</div>
 </ng-template>
</ng-select>

I already updated your "stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wziwui".

Comment: What if I don't have an ng-model? Can we use any other approach?

Comment: If you don't have model than save value in one simple variable in component.
For example, make "selected" as simple component variable and update value based on selected option.

Answer (score 2):

You can put a [template](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/templates) inside the `<ng-option>`, and add the directive `ng-option-tmp`:

```
<ng-select [items]="listArrayManyElements" placeholder="Select" [(ngModel)]="Selected" 
           bindLabel="name" bindValue="name">
    <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item">
        <div [title]="item.name">{{item.name}}</div>
    </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

I've updated your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wziwui?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: "<div [title]="list.name">{{list.name}}</div>" it consider as a options value and div also printed in the list.

Comment: @AniketAvhad I've updated my answer, you have to bind a value to the `ng-option`

Comment: If i use your solution then problem like this, please have a look into https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivb52r?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html"

Comment: @AniketAvhad I've browsed a bit through the source code, and you should use the `ng-option-tmp` directive

Comment: @Poul thanks for answers... In this example... stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wziwui?file=src/app/… I select first option.. "Loreum....." after selection ... We can see selected item...When I hover on the selected value... I would like to see the title( as the name is too big and user cant see full value)same as when I open dropdown options and hover over... I am able to see title.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap library to display a tooltip in parallel with ng-select:

template:

```
<ng-select [ngbTooltip]="tipContent" container="body" placement="bottom" placeholder="Select" (change)="onChange($event)">
      <ng-option *ngFor="let list of listArray" title="{{list.name}}"> {{list.name}}  
     </ng-option>
</ng-select>

<ng-template #tipContent>{{listArray[0].name}}</ng-template>
```

ts:

```
listArray = [
    {name: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"}
];
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ntmcxp)

I added a demo using only bootstrap with no external libraries. Hover on the options to see the tooltip (takes a couple of seconds until it is displayed):
[New Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d2vaor)

Comment: I don't have a single value in array, Having up to 15 objects so, In this case how it will work.

Comment: I added a demo using only bootstrap with no external libraries to meet your requirements. Don't know if it is ok for you but take a look in case you want to try it. Using ng-select is a bit tricky when you have multiple items to display a tooltip.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but bootstrap dropdown looking very bad. I don't want to use that.

Comment: worked for me, just added placement="right" container="body" to make it fully work

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but using span could be another solution:

```
<ng-select placeholder="Select" (change)="onChange($event)">
    <ng-option *ngFor="let list of listArray" 
       title="{{list.name}}"><span [title]="list.name">{{list.name}}</span></ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom directive like that:

```
import { ContentChild, Directive, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgSelectComponent } from "@ng-select/ng-select";

@Directive({
selector: '[admSelectTitle]'
})

export class SelectTitleDirective implements OnInit {

@ContentChild(NgSelectComponent) select: NgSelectComponent;

@ContentChild(NgSelectComponent, { read: ElementRef }) selectNative: ElementRef;

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
ngOnInit() {
    if (!this.select) {
        return;
    }
    const nativeElement = this.selectNative.nativeElement;
    nativeElement.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        const listOfPickedElements = nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.ng-value-label.ng-star-inserted');
        listOfPickedElements.forEach((el) => {
            el.setAttribute('title', el.innerHTML);
        })

        const listOfAvailableOptions = nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.ng-dropdown-panel-items.scroll-host .ng-option.ng-option-marked');
        listOfAvailableOptions.forEach((v) => {
            v.setAttribute('title', v.innerText)
        })

    })
}
}
```

After that you can simply use it:

```
<ng-select admSelectTitle [items]="yourItems" bindLabel="name" bindValue="id" class="anyClass" formControlName="anyName" [multiple]="true">
                    <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item">
                        {{ item.name }}
                    </ng-template>
                </ng-select>
```

now there are tooltips on ng-select and on ng-options elements.
Sorry for bad English=)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-select placeholder="Select" (change)="onChange($event)">
      <ng-option *ngFor="let list of listArray">
         <div title="{{list.name}}"> 
            {{list.name}}
         </div>
      </ng-option>
 </ng-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution to the  problem was to add "FormsModule" to the module that imports the "NgSelectModule"

you module should look something like this:

```
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
FormsModule,
NgSelectModule,
]
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case i use ngx-bootstrap and ng select. this is the example [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04Vzw.png)

```html
<div>
  <ng-template #itemTol>
    {{getTooltips(items, value)}}
  </ng-template>
    <ng-select [items]="items" #ngitem[clearable]="false" [tooltip]="itemTol" [isDisabled]="ngitem.isOpen" bindLabel="text" bindValue="value" placeholder="Please select" name="sales_agent" formControlName="name">
    <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item">
      <div [tooltip]="item.text" placement="bottom">{{item.text}}</div>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-select>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be nice to have some explanation about why your code resolves the question.