# How to add Tooltip when use ng-select in angular 5?

Tags: angular

I have used ng-select in dropdown, when user mouseover the dropdown list, it should show tooltip.
**Code:**

```
<label>Grouping</label>
  <ng-select [items]="accounts"
            bindLabel="name"
            bindValue="name"
            groupBy="country"
            [(ngModel)]="selectedAccount">
  </ng-select>
```

Component

```
 accounts = [
    { name: 'Adam', email: 'adam@email.com', age: 12, country: 'United States' },
    { name: 'Samantha', email: 'samantha@email.com', age: 30, country: 'United States' },
    { name: 'Amalie', email: 'amalie@email.com', age: 12, country: 'Argentina' },
    { name: 'Estefanía', email: 'estefania@email.com', age: 21, country: 'Argentina' },
    { name: 'Adrian', email: 'adrian@email.com', age: 21, country: 'Ecuador' },
    { name: 'Wladimir', email: 'wladimir@email.com', age: 30, country: 'Ecuador' },
    { name: 'Natasha', email: 'natasha@email.com', age: 54, country: 'Ecuador' }
   
];
```

**Note:**
I need tooltip in ng-select dropdown list.

I tried with **title** attribute, but it not working.

Example:

When user mouse over the dropdown list, need to show ToolTip.

**Question**

How to add tootip in ng-select using angular5?

Your suggestion will helpful for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show tooltip on @ng-select/ng-select options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51683400/how-to-show-tooltip-on-ng-select-ng-select-options)

Answer (score 5):

you can use ng-template to achive this

```
<ng-select [items]="accounts"
                bindLabel="name"
                bindValue="name"
                groupBy="country"
                [(ngModel)]="selectedAccount">

        <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item">
        <div title="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</div>
        </ng-template>
    </ng-select>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. What if we need to show the title for a selected item?

Answer (score 3):

Use `*ngFor` to create `options` and give options the tooltip which you need.[check this Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2dyiq6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: thanks for the answer. What if we need to show the title for a selected item?