# How to show the all text when mouse is over

Tags: html, angular, typescript, for-loop, mouseover

I have one select returning some options from api, the problem is that some options are bigger than text box and dont show the all text to the user

```
<div class="form-group my-4">
   <label class="mb-1">{{'Área_de_Interesse' | translate}}</label>
   <ng-select [multiple]="false" name="areaInteresse" placeholder="Selecione" formControlName="areaInteresse">
       <ng-option *ngFor="let item of areasDeInteresse" [value]="item">{{ item.nomeAreaInteresse }}</ng-option>
   </ng-select>
</div>
```

I need to somehow show all the text when the user hovers over the option, I was trying to loop through the options and pass their value to a variable: "optionName"

```
teste(){
    this.dominioService.buscarAreaInteresse().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.areasDeInteresse = data;
      this.areasDeInteresse = this.areasDeInteresse.filter(x => x.ativo == true);
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        this.optionName[i] = data[i].nomeAreaInteresse;
        console.log(this.optionName)
      }
    });
  }
```

But I still have no idea how to individualize each option and how to make them appear in full when the mouse is over

Comment: I searched online and found an answer....but also this is a dupe question Does this answer your question? [How to show tooltip on @ng-select/ng-select options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51683400/how-to-show-tooltip-on-ng-select-ng-select-options)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-select [items]="areasDeInteresse" bindLabel="name" bindValue="name">
    <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item">
    <div title="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</div>
    </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

Comment: It worked but no completely because at the time of selecting the option it was not marked in the box, I found a slightly simpler solution

Comment: For others, you should post the solution you found.

Answer (score 0):

Like this you can select your option and it will appear in your text box

```
<div class="form-group my-4">
  <label class="mb-1">{{'Área_de_Interesse' | translate}}</label>
  <ng-select [multiple]="false" name="areaInteresse" placeholder="Selecione" formControlName="areaInteresse">
     <ng-option *ngFor="let item of areasDeInteresse" title="{{item.nomeAreaInteresse}}" [value]="item"> <span [title]="item.nomeAreaInteresse">{{item.nomeAreaInteresse}}</span> </ng-option>
  </ng-select>
</div>
```